# Plotbands to highcharts based on category

Tags: highcharts

I have categories that are grouped and sorted by a sort order 1-7.
So group 1 has 3 categories in it. 
So the first 3 categories belong to group one, next 4 belongs to group 2 and so on.

Is it possible to apply plot bands based on the categories?

Thanks

JS fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/juliangurung/v73dcjs0/

Im not sure how to add plotbands which looks at my categories

```
xAxis: [{
    plotBands: [{
        color: 'orange', // Color value
        from: 3, // Start of the plot band
        to: 4 // End of the plot band
      }],
}]
```

Comment: Can you create fiddle for this ?

Comment: Could you please post live example of your chart like jsFiddle? It is possible to add plotBand in Highcharts: http://jsfiddle.net/L4xzp20h/

Comment: updated with js fiddle

Comment: @Julian: For your categories, since they're dynamic, how do you determine which group they belong to? There may be a way to grab those values before you set the chart options and fix the plot bands that way.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can simply use `plotBands`. Take a look at examples posted below.

API Reference:
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.plotBands

Examples:
http://jsfiddle.net/d9pn98jL/
https://jsfiddle.net/kryeo92u/

Comment: the problem with this is that it's assuming, what the to and from will be. In my case the grouping are dynamic and each group size will not be the same. Although, I suppose I can compute each to and from when the grouping changes.

Comment: You can add plot bands on load event, you just need to know how you want to divide them. Knowing how many categories belongs to specific groups will make it all easy.